# with vb.net, has anyone figured out a way to print an entire scrollable form?

Tags: vb.net, forms, printing

I have a form which of course is scrollable and I need to print all of the contents of the form on multiple pages.

I've tried everything I can find using PrintForm, but it only prints one page and only what can fit on the screen.

I've looked at PrintDocument, but that forces me to recreate the entire document formatted for the printer. I need to print what is already there.

I do not have any scrollable elements inside the form, just the parent form itself is scrollable.

I've scoured the internet and I can't find anything. I'll even buy a control if one is out there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a `PrintForm component` to the form and then

```
PrintForm1.Print(Me, PowerPacks.Printing.PrintForm.PrintOption.Scrollable)
```

valter