# printing scrollable panel with image inside in vb

Tags: vb.net, printing, panel, scrollable

Good Day everyone. i have a problem in printing the  image in my scrollable panel. can anyone help me with this?

i wanted to resize the images first (so it can fit the 8.5 by 11" paper) before showing it in print preview then printing it

in my case, i have a form(form1) with a panel (dock=fill) and i wanted to print the images (2 images) inside it. but, the trigger of the printing of image is in the next form

in btnnext(form1)
     Form2.Show()
     Me.Hide()

and the printing code is in the form2. i am new in vb and i don't have any idea about printing the scrollable panel. i tried different codes in other forums but it didn't print the whole image but only the screenshot of the form. any response will be appreciated., thank you so much

---

```
Public Class Form2

Private WithEvents pd As New Printing.PrintDocument
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Using bmp As New Bitmap(Form1.pb1.Width, Form1.pb1.Height)
        Form1.panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, Form1.pb1.Width, Form1.pb1.Height))
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, e.MarginBounds)
    End Using
End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    PrintDocument1.Print()
End Sub 
End Class
```

-
^it only prints what you can see in the screen. not the whole panel..

Comment: are you using `panel.DrawToBitmap()` ?

Comment: Using bmp As New Bitmap(Form1.pb1.Width, Form1.pb1.Height)
            Form1.pb1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, Form1.pb1.Width, Form1.pb1.Height))
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, e.MarginBounds)
        End Using (i used this code and it's working) only problem now is print preview...i have no idea in print preview..

Comment: `DrawToBitmap` always takes a screenshot of the panel thus only picking up what's visible. This question was asked before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22056099/with-vb-net-has-anyone-figured-out-a-way-to-print-an-entire-scrollable-form?rq=1 however it was not never answered

Comment: oops. i still have a problem. i have 2 images so using form1.pb1.drawtobitmap will not work. i used Form1.panel1.DrawToBitmap but it only prints what you can see in the form (not the whole images in the panel)

Comment: you can always generate two different images and print them on separate pages in the `PrintPage` event

Comment: problem is, i don't want to separate the two images because the first image is a map and the second one is the locator(it is above the first image) is there any way i can print the images inside the panel in one page?

Comment: well yes post the whole `PrintPage` event in your question so I can help you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basically, keep everything the same, but instead of printing the whole first image on the whole page, and print the second image to a ratio of its location and size relative to the MarginBounds

```
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    Using bmp As New Bitmap(Form1.pb1.Width, Form1.pb1.Height)
        Form1.pb1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, New Rectangle(0, 0, Form1.pb1.Width, Form1.pb1.Height))
        'Print pb1 to fill the whole page
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, e.MarginBounds)
    End Using
    Using bmp2 As New Bitmap(Form1.pb2.Width, Form1.pb2.Height)
        Form1.pb2.DrawToBitmap(bmp2, New Rectangle(0, 0, Form1.pb2.Width, Form1.pb2.Height))

        Dim x as Double = Form1.pb2.Location.X - Form1.pb1.Location.X
        x = x * e.MarginBounds.Width / Form1.pb1.Width
        x = x + e.MarginBounds.X

        Dim y as Double = Form1.pb2.Location.Y - Form1.pb1.Location.Y
        y = y * e.MarginBounds.Height / Form1.pb1.Height
        y = y + e.MarginBounds.Y

        Dim width as Double = Form1.pb2.width
        width = width * e.MarginBounds.Width / Form1.pb1.Width

        Dim height as Double = Form1.pb2.Height
        height = height * e.MarginBounds.Height / Form1.pb1.Height

        e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp2, New Rectangle(x, y, width, height))
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: but i didn't downvoted it? anyway, it shows the second image but the problem is it shows the actual size of the image (doesn't locate the right part of the first image or it doesn't show what is shown in the panel) while the first one is stretched.

Comment: No I know it wasn't you :) I was referring to whoever did downvote... Anyway, try and play around with the two lines `e.Graphics.DrawImage` as they are controlling the ratio of the two images. I've set it: first image: start from top left corner and up to half the page, and the second from the half of the page to the far right

Comment: it actually printed the first one in the left side and second one on the right side of the page. you're right. but my problem is, i wanted to print what is shown in the scrollable panel. because the arrow/locator(second image) is important. it needs to be in the right position

Comment: can you post a screenshot or something as I'm not sure I understand how you want it

Comment: i can't post an image :( but it looks like this> https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ1yC1iww_tAHZZqxQFUGph5aypsQS3vH-UG8tp0jAjNx_oDyKR (but with scrollbars and imagining that the first image is the map and the second one is the black ) sorry for the late comment

Comment: ohhh so you need to translate the pb's positions in the panel to the page's marginbounds :/ thats a bit of maths involved... shouldn't be that hard... if you print pb1 to scale on the marginbounds, does it look good?

Comment: I'll finish when i can as I have an appointment. See if you understand what i did and try to figure out the width and height of the second image

Comment: i'm sorry but i don't know how to? but i'll try to. thank you so much!  :)

Comment: i'm getting an error in ' e.Graphics.DrawImage(bmp, e.MarginBounds.X)' --> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'DrawImage' can be called with these arguments:
    'Public Sub DrawImage(image As System.Drawing.Image, destPoints() As System.Drawing.Point)': Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of System.Drawing.Point'.
    'Public Sub DrawImage(image As System.Drawing.Image, destPoints() As System.Drawing.PointF)': Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to '1-dimensional array of System.Drawing.PointF'.
...etc

Comment: fixed... I meant to write `e.MarginBounds`